# Using the v2 Box API, how do I get comment id ?

Tags: box-api

How do I get id for created comment, using the v2 Box API?
Method get event return source null:

```
"type": "event",
"event_id": "a9051dcb5f7a54e94469d481c2d40efc878953ff",
"created_by": { ...},
"created_at": "2012-09-28T08:07:08-07:00",
"recorded_at": "2012-09-28T08:07:09-07:00",
"event_type": "COMMENT_CREATE",
"session_id": "16727932385065b9e714973",
"source": null
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  We've filed this as a bug, and will get it fixed as soon as we can.  This is missing in the /events endpoint.